# Replace var in Sjasm macro

Tags: assembly, z80

I'm creating a Sjasm macro, so I can use:

```
L_E52A:
        ld hl, $58A0
        ld c, $12

        _do
                inc hl
                ld b, $1E

                _do 
                        ld (hl), a
                        inc hl
                _djnz
                inc hl
                dec c
        _while nz

        ret
```

I scratch this, but it doesn't work:

```
DLOOP_3 = 0
DLOOP_2 = 0
DLOOP_TOP = 0

    MACRO DLOOP_PUSH arg

DLOOP_3 = DLOOP_2
DLOOP_2 = DLOOP_TOP
DLOOP_TOP = arg
    ENDM

    MACRO DLOOP_POP

DLOOP_TOP = DLOOP_2
DLOOP_2 = DLOOP_3
DLOOP_3 =  0
    ENDM

    MACRO _do
        DLOOP_PUSH $
DLOOP_TOP:
    ENDM

    MACRO _while flag

        jr flag, DLOOP_TOP
        DLOOP_POP
    ENDM


    MACRO _djnz

        djnz DLOOP_TOP
        DLOOP_POP
    ENDM
```

The `DLOOP_TOP` isn't replaced with the actual value of `DLOOP_TOP`
I'd like to have this working so I can see the asm a little bit mot like js

I'm a noob on Z80 asm.

Please help.

Comment: Can you post the exact commands you used to assemble that, as well as your environment and also the output?

Answer (score 2):

[The assembler](https://github.com/Konamiman/Sjasm) knows "reusable labels", see [the documentation](http://xl2s.tk/sjasmman3.html#s2).

So you don't need the stack to organize your loop labels.

```
    MACRO _do
1
    ENDM

    MACRO _while flag
        jr flag, 1b
    ENDM

    MACRO _djnz
        djnz 1b
    ENDM
```

Comment: That whould result that the "_while nz" jumps to the second "_do", and I want it to jump to the first one.

Comment: @RuiCosta Darn, you're right. Unfortunately I don't have that assembler and refrain to install it. ;-) Then local labels might work, but I have to work for money now...

Answer (score 0):

I notice that I dont need to create a label inside _do, i can just do :

```
DLOOP_5 = 0
DLOOP_4 = 0
DLOOP_3 = 0
DLOOP_2 = 0
DLOOP_TOP = 0

    MACRO DLOOP_PUSH arg
DLOOP_5 = DLOOP_4
DLOOP_4 = DLOOP_3
DLOOP_3 = DLOOP_2
DLOOP_2 = DLOOP_TOP
DLOOP_TOP = arg
    ENDM

    MACRO DLOOP_POP

DLOOP_TOP = DLOOP_2
DLOOP_2 = DLOOP_3
DLOOP_3 = DLOOP_4
DLOOP_4 = DLOOP_5
DLOOP_5 =  0

    ENDM

    MACRO _do
        DLOOP_PUSH $

    ENDM

    MACRO _while flag

        jr flag, DLOOP_TOP
        DLOOP_POP
    ENDM


    MACRO _djnz

        djnz DLOOP_TOP
        DLOOP_POP
    ENDM
```